# How do I access a class method optionally without creating an instance

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm relatively new to python and getting my head around OOP. I'm making a class to perform some basic methods on data, but ideally i'd like to access those class methods as regular functions without necessarily creating an instance first.

I have the following code set up for MyMethod containing a single method 'clip_sphere', which takes in xyz coordinates as an array and returns coordinates that are inside a sphere centered at 'center' with radius 'radius'

```py
import numpy as np

class MyMethod:

    def __init__(self,xyz):
        self.xyz = xyz

    def clip_sphere(self, center, radius):

        self.xyz = self.xyz - np.array(center).reshape(1,-1)
        r = (np.sum(self.xyz**2, axis = 1))**0.5
        idx = r < radius

        xyz_clip = self.xyz[idx,:]
        self.clip = xyz_clip

        return xyz_clip
```

what i would like to do is be able to run clip sphere in two ways, wither by 1:

```py
C = MyMethod(xyz)
xyz_clip = C.clip_sphere(center =[0,0,0],radius = 2)
```

or simply by calling it as a function like:

```py
xyz_clip = clip_sphere(xyz,center =[0,0,0],radius = 2)
```

Prefereably without rewriting as an ordinary function. Is this possible to do with some decorators? or is this even possible at all.

EDIT: After looking through some of the answers, I guess what I'm asking is how to get a function like numpy reshape. as this works by both allowing a statement like:

```py
a = np.reshape(np.array([1,2,3]),[3,1])
```

Which is acting like a function
As well as:

```py
 a = np.array([1,2,3]) 
 a.reshape([3,1])
```

which is acting like a class method

Comment: `xyz_clip = Myethod(xyz).clip_sphere(center =[0,0,0], radius = 2)`

Comment: "i'd like to access those class methods as regular functions without necessarily creating an instance first." Then these should regular functions, not class method

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Or a classmethod

Comment: Object oriented programming is typically used when you have some "object" or "thing" that has state which can be modified or used by calling functions. For example, you might create a `Sphere` class that has a `radius` and `center`. What you are doing here doesn't seem to call for a class at all.

Comment: What about static methods?

Comment: Also, what happens if you call `C.clip_sphere()` multiple times in a row. I think it won't do what you want because you change the value of `self.xyz`. Also you assign to `self.clip` but never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind how descriptors work, you can make a small modification to a properly written `clip_sphere` method that will let you run the method as either a method, or as a `classmethod` that accepts coordinates as the first argument:

```
def clip_sphere(self, center, radius):
    xyz = self.xyz if isinstance(self, __class__) else self
    xyz -= np.array(center).reshape(1,-1)
    r = (np.sum(self.xyz**2, axis = 1))**0.5
    idx = r < radius
    xyz_clip = self.xyz[idx,:]
    if isinstance(self, __class__):
        self.clip = xyz_clip
        self.xyz = xyz
    return xyz_clip
```

You can call it either as a method:

```
>>> xyz = ...
>>> MyMethod().clip_sphere(...)
```

or as a `classmethod`:

```
>>> MyMethod.clip_sphere(xyz, ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is sort-of built-in - all you need to do is get the function from the class' namespace:

```
C = MyMethod(xyz)
xyz_clip = MyMethod.clip_sphere(C, center =[0,0,0], radius = 2)
```

However, this still requires that you have an instance of the class. The issue is that the code is written to find `xyz` etc. attributes *in a specific named object*, the one named `self`. (There is nothing special about the name `self` in Python beyond convention.)

If you really need to be able to use `xyz` for this functionality, then the sane approach is to just write a plain function that handles it:

```
# At top level
def clip(xyz, center, radius):
    xyz -= np.array(center).reshape(1,-1)
    r = (np.sum(xyz**2, axis = 1))**0.5
    idx = r < radius
    return xyz[idx,:]
```

And then to avoid repetitive code, you can use this to implement the method:

```
# inside the class
def clip_sphere(self, center, radius):
    # This part of the process needs to be repeated, because the
    # `xyz` variable during the `clip` call is a separate name.
    # However, you should consider whether you *actually* want to modify
    # the object's `self.xyz` as a part of this process. My guess is you do not.
    self.xyz -= np.array(center).reshape(1,-1)
    self.clip = clip(self.xyz, center, radius) # uses the top-level `clip`.
```

Comment: This is indeed the saner approach. Not sure why OP picked mine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a standalone function, rather than a class/object:

```
def clip_sphere(xyz, center, radius):

    xyz = xyz - np.array(center).reshape(1,-1)
    r = (np.sum(xyz**2, axis = 1))**0.5
    idx = r < radius

    xyz_clip = xyz[idx,:]
    clip = xyz_clip

    return xyz_clip
```

Comment: This method is part of a large class, with many other methods all which work well for that specific class, but I was hoping I could quickly use this method (or others) on standalone data (in this case xyz) without creating a class instance and without copy/pasting or defining another function like clip_sphere_func as you have created here.

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly why you are writing a class in the first place. What are you expecting it to gain you over just calling the functions on the standalone data in the first place? What does the class *conceptually represent*?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global function named `clip_sphere()`:

```
def clip_sphere(xyz, center, radius):
   return MyMethod(xyz).clip_sphere(center, radius)
```

But doing this makes me wonder why you need the class at all. From what I can tell that you are doing here, it would probably make more sense to create a `Sphere` class. This is clearly an object with some attributes: `radius` and `center`. Then you can add a `clip()` method to do what you want:

```
class Sphere:
   def __init__(center, radius):
      self.center = center
      self.radius = radius

   def clip(x, y, z):
      # code goes here
```

### Response to edit:

> After looking through some of the answers, I guess what I'm asking is how to get a function like numpy reshape. as this works by both allowing a statement like:
>
> ```
> a = np.reshape(np.array([1,2,3]),[3,1])
> ```
>
> Which is acting like a function As well as:
>
> ```
> a = np.array([1,2,3]) 
> a.reshape([3,1])
> ```

This is **two different functions**, not two different ways of calling the same function.

Comment: this is a simple method in a larger class of things i'm trying to create. but it would be handy to access certain functions on standalone data (xyz) without creating an instance. Just wondering if this is possible without rewriting as another function

Comment: @AlecDay No it is not possible to call these methods as they are without an instance of the class. As other's have pointed out, the `self` parameter has to be an instance of the class. You could make it a `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` but then no longer have access to `self.xyz` or other fields.

Comment: I guess i'm wondering how a method like numpy.reshape works by both allowing a statement like ```a = np.reshape(np.array([1,2,3]),[3,1])``` as well as ```a = np.array([1,2,3]) , a.reshape([3,1])```

Comment: @AlecDay In that case, there are two functions named `reshape()`. One is in the `numpy` module. The other is in the `array` class. So you are **not** calling the same function in two different ways. Rather you are calling two different functions.